# reflect value Interface and pointer receiver

Tags: go, interface

In the mongodb driver for golang there is the following piece of code:

```
case reflect.Struct:
    if z, ok := v.Interface().(Zeroer); ok {
        return z.IsZero()
    }
    return false
```

Interface Zeroer is defined like this:

```
type Zeroer interface {
    IsZero() bool
}
```

When I implement my struct with

```
func (id SomeStruct) IsZero() bool {
    return id.ID == ""
}
```

it works. But when I implement the IsZero method with a pointer receiver:

```
func (id *SomeStruct) IsZero() bool {
        return id.ID == ""
 }
```

the type assertion fails and IsZero does not get executed.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You haven't shown the code that's failing, but it means you're not passing in a pointer, which is the type required for that receiver.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/S_kREJQkf4w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably somewhere above the `case reflect.Struct` there is a switch on `reflect.ValueOf(...).Kind()`

If you look at the `Kind`s in the reflect package, [docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind)

`Struct` is one of the kinds and `Ptr` is another. In the switch statement it is not matching because the kind `*SomeStruct` as defined in the receiver of the `IsZero()` method is `Ptr` and not `Struct`.

You'd need to do `v.Elem().Interface().(Zeroer)` to get the underlying element

Runnable example here https://play.golang.org/p/tx1zgD7Ri0E